# iOS crashing using 'capture' HTML attribute on audio upload

Tags: html, ios

Input html which correctly opens user's audio upload options -- however does not show record option.

```
<input type="file" name="audio_upload" accept="audio/*" required />
```

When I add the `capture` attribute it crashes my browser on iOS. It does not do it on Android:

```
<input type="file" name="audio_upload" accept="audio/*" capture required />
```

---

Here is a code snippet to try for yourself:

```html
    <input type="file" name="audio_upload" accept="audio/*" required />

<input type="file" name="audio_upload" accept="audio/*" capture required />
```

I have tried on my iPhone 11 and it crashes on safari. My friend has also tried and it crashed on his iPhone 6s.

I have tried just my android s7 edge and it does not crash.

Is this the same error? https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202039

Am I trying to do something that shouldn't be allowed?

Thanks